# Why tar hangs failing to extract a file

Tags: linux, unix, tar, solaris

I am using a Solaris 11 system and am trying to extract from a tar file which I know to be OK, but when I try to extract it, tar hangs. I don't get any feedback from tar.

What areas of Solaris should I check to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Well, in this case the fault was in the system not being able to properly access the NIS server and thus not being able to provide proper permissions information to tar.

It seems like a case of "chicken and egg". I don't know if the NIS server failed and caused service network-inetd to fault, or network-inetd faulted first and access to NIS was blocked.

Anyways, going into /etc/nsswitch.conf and removing all references to nis (or ldap if you use it) from the file and restarting the system helped. Solaris came back up, tar is working and you could go back and put the nis reference as before.

All is back to normal.